# Java RMI Connection Refused to Host

Tags: java, network-programming, rmi

As an assignment for a class I had to program a client server pair that recquested and provided information about the server's computer. Date and time, netstat, etc... 
At first I programmed it to use sockets but now for the second program we have to make it use RMI. I have been running into a lot of problems making the RMI protocol work. The client fails when I try to call a method. It gets to the line "clientRequest.getSomething();" and then fails. I am getting errors saying "java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: " I'm not sure why this is occurring. I have looked at other questions and I am starting the rmi registry before running the server with the command " rmiregistry & " If I understand correctly that should start the rmiregistry on port 1099. These do compile correctly but I haven't included all of the files necessary for everything to work.

ServerImpl.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;


public class ServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface{

int thisConnectionNumber = 0;
String request = "";
String something = "123131231";



public static void main(String argv[]){ //Start Main

try{
    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","192.168.100.115");
    ServerImpl request = new ServerImpl();
    Naming.rebind("Request", request);

}

catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
//End Main

public ServerImpl() throws RemoteException{ //Constructor

}

public void getSomething() throws RemoteException {
System.out.println(something);
}


public String connection(String thisRequest) throws RemoteException {

    String linuxCommands[] = new String[6]; //Array of linux commands to execute processes
    linuxCommands[0] = "date";
    linuxCommands[1] = "uptime";
    linuxCommands[2] = "free -l";
    linuxCommands[3] = "netstat -v";
    linuxCommands[4] = "who -a";
    linuxCommands[5] = "ps aux";

String inFromClient;
String outFromServer;

inFromClient = thisRequest;
int clientRequestInt;
++thisConnectionNumber;



    try{
        clientRequestInt = Integer.parseInt(inFromClient);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       clientRequestInt = -1;
    }


      if( clientRequestInt > 0 && clientRequestInt <7) //Begin if/else
      {
      outFromServer = runLinuxCommand(linuxCommands[clientRequestInt - 1]);
      System.out.println("Output sent to client");
      System.out.println("Ending Connection Number: " + thisConnectionNumber);
      return "Connection Number: " + thisConnectionNumber + "\n" + outFromServer + "\n";


      }
      else
         {
         System.out.println("Error sent to client");
     System.out.println("Ending Connection Number: " + thisConnectionNumber);
         return "Connection Number: " + thisConnectionNumber + " -  " + "Error in request";
         } //End if/else
}
//End Connection Method


public static String runLinuxCommand(String command){

String processOutput ="";
String s ="";
Process p;

    try{
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
       BufferedReader processReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
       while((s = processReader.readLine()) != null )
        {
        processOutput += s + "\n";
        }
    processOutput += "\0";
       }

     catch (Exception e) {}

return processOutput;
//End runLinuxCommand Method
}

}
//End Server Class
```

ClientThreading.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;

public class ClientThreading implements Runnable{

private String hostName = "";
private String request = "";
private String requestString = "";
int threadNumber;


//Constructor
public ClientThreading(String hostName, String request, String requestString, int threadNumber)
    {
    this.hostName = hostName;
    this.request = request;
    this.requestString = requestString;
    this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
    }


//Method that actaully make socket connection and prints resutls
public void run() {

String responseFromServerFinal = "";
String responseFromServer = "";
threadNumber++;
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
String URL = "rmi://" + hostName;

try{




        //Lookup server object
        ServerInterface clientRequest = (ServerInterface)Naming.lookup(URL + "/Request");

        LatencyTimer latency = new LatencyTimer(threadNumber, requestString);

            latency.start();
            //Start Timer
            System.out.println("asdsada"); //Printing to test where it fails
            clientRequest.getSomething();
            System.out.println("2");       //Printing to test where it fails
            responseFromServerFinal = clientRequest.connection(request);
            System.out.println("12313131"); //Printing to test where it fails
            /*
            outToServer.writeBytes(request + "\n");
            while(!(responseFromServer = fromServer.readLine()).equals("\0"))
            {
            responseFromServerFinal += responseFromServer + "\n";
            }
            //End While for receiving info from Server
            */



            latency.end();
            //End Timer

            latency.printTimeString();
            long timeInMs = latency.printTimeInt();
            Client.timeArray[threadNumber-1] = timeInMs;

            System.out.println(responseFromServerFinal);
            //Print full info from Server

            //latency.printTimeString();
            //long timeInMs = latency.printTimeInt();
            //Client.timeArray[threadNumber-1] = timeInMs;

   } catch (Exception e)   {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
//   } catch (IOException e) {
//      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + hostName);
//      System.exit(1);
   }
 }

}
```

ServerInterface

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ServerInterface extends Remote {

    public String connection(String thisRequest) throws RemoteException;
    public void getSomething() throws RemoteException;

}
```

Errors

```
UNFCSD\n00832607@ciswkstn116:~/Project2/Actual$ java -Djava.security.policy=policy.txt Client 192.168.100.115
1. Host Current Date and Time
2. Host uptime
3. Host memory use
4. Host Netstat
5. Host current users
6. Host running processes
7. Quit
1
How many threads would you like?
1


asdsada
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at ServerImpl_Stub.getSomething(Unknown Source)
    at ClientThreading.run(ClientThreading.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: This should work, although I'm surprised you can set the system property *after* installing the security manager. Are you sure this is the real code?

Comment: Yes this is the real code that I am running on the machines. Why is that surprising? I am kind of grasping at air here to try and make this work.

Comment: It is surprising because you don't mention a policy file, so I would expect the security manager to throw an [`AccessControlException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessControlException.html) to prevent you from setting system properties after you install it. Can you try switching the system property and security manager lines around?

Comment: Very puzzled by this. Setting `java.rmi.server.hostname` as you have should fix this. Can you print out `clientRequest` after you do the `lookup()` and post the output here? Edit it into your question.

Comment: Your client class doesn't run with the security manager that it installs. This cannot possibly be the real code, or you have left out some important information such as the .policy file.